# Renderizar múltiples tablas con flask

Tags: html, python, base-de-datos, flask, datatable

Tengo mi archivo de Flask que llama a unos endpoint para traer unos datos. Si se envía formulario 1 realiza el filtro con los datos requeridos a la db y aplica lo mismo con el formulario 2, ambos se renderizan en la misma página html.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        div_id = request.form.get('div_id')

        # Verificar qué formulario se envió
        if 'tabla_sitio_fecha_inicio' in request.form and 'tabla_sitio_fecha_fin' in request.form:
            # Si se envió el formulario dos
            start_date = request.form['tabla_sitio_fecha_inicio']
            end_date = request.form['tabla_sitio_fecha_fin']
            filtro = request.form['tabla_sitio_filtro']
            valor = request.form['tabla_sitio_valor']
            datos1 = obtener_datos_por_fechas(start_date, end_date, filtro, valor)

            return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data1=datos1, scroll_to_div=div_id)
        
        elif 'tabla_sitio_gral_filtro' in request.form and 'tabla_sitio_gral_valor' in request.form:
            # Si se envió el formulario uno
            ts_gral_filtro = request.form['tabla_sitio_gral_filtro']
            ts_gral_valor = request.form['tabla_sitio_gral_valor']
            datos2 = obtener_datos_por_filtro(ts_gral_filtro, ts_gral_valor)

            return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data2=datos2, scroll_to_div=div_id)
        else:
            return "Error: formulario inválido"
    else:     
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # Si no es una solicitud POST, obtener datos iniciales
            datos_iniciales = obtener_datos_iniciales()

            if datos_iniciales is not None:
                return render_template('one_page.html', fetched_data=datos_iniciales, scroll_to_div=None)
            else:
                return "Error al obtener datos iniciales"
```

Hasta aquí funciona bien. Mi problema es al mandar algún formulario desde el html, me actualiza la tabla correspondiente pero me elimina los datos de la otra tabla, quedando vacía.

Hay alguna forma de que al mandar el formulario solo me actualice la tabla correspondiente y los datos de la otra tabla queden como estaban antes de recargar la página?

Esta es una de mis tablas. La otra tiene un funcionamiento similar pero obtiene la data de la otra variable.

```
                <tbody>
                    {% if fetched_data2 is defined %}
                        {% for data in fetched_data2 %}
                            <!-- Mostrar datos iniciales -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[0] }}" name="cliente_0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[1] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[2] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[3] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[22] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% for data in fetched_data %}
                            <!-- Mostrar datos filtrados -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[0] }}" name="cliente_0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[1] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[2] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[3] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ data[22] }}" name="cliente_1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar las funciones "obtener_datos_por..." Por favor?